# Bootbox - Disable BUtton

Tags: bootbox

I can't seem to find much information on Bootbox, I was hoping that I could disable the search button if invalid. Two elements on the modal, one needs to be provided. I would have thought that would be a parm called disabled etc which you could pass logic through to, but the code below doesn't work. Am I missing something, seems like a basic requirement to have.

```
search(){          
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Search Options",
        message: jQuery('#searchCriteria').html(),
        buttons: {
            cancel: {                    
                label: 'Cancel', 
                className: 'btn btn-default'
            },
            confirm: {
                disabled: this.canSearch(),
                label: 'Search', 
                className: 'btn-primary btn btn-info', 
                callback: function() {
                    this.searchOptions("test","1");
                    }
                } 
            },
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: only `disabled` doesn't work? and everything else is fine?

Comment: Yes, I guessed at disabled, as I thought surely they have that as a parm. But the button does not grey out. Ive tried disabled: true, disabled "true", disabled: 'true', disabled: 1. To see if its the logic in canSearch(), however these do nothing either

Comment: Unfortunately there's no option like this in `bootbox`. Its opensource you can edit to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something like this before. I accomplished it by using the init function to apply a "watcher" to the form I injected into the dialog.

```
var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    message: $('#my-template').html(),
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: 'Cancel',
            callback: function(){ dialog.modal('hide'); }
        },
        submit: {
            label: 'Submit',
            className: 'submit-form btn-primary',
            callback: function() {
                // ... submit form via ajax?
            }
        }
    }
    // ... the rest
});

dialog.init(function(){
    var formID = '#my-form';

    $(formID)
        .on('change input', '.form-control', function(e){
            checkFormAndEnable(formID);
        })
        .on('submit', function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
});

function checkFormAndEnable(selector) {
    var form = $(selector);

    var count = form.find('input[type!=hidden]').length;
    var emptyCount = form.find('input[type!=hidden]').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) !== "";
    }).length;

    var canValidate = count == emptyCount;
    if (canValidate) {
        dialog.find('.submit-form').prop({ 'disabled': !form.valid() });
    }
    else {
        dialog.find('.submit-form').prop({ 'disabled': true });
    }
}
```

This assumes you're using [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). If not, you would replace `!form.valid()` with whatever you use to validate your inputs. You can also replace `init` with `.on('shown.bs.modal')`, especially if the form gets shown multiple times (init seems to only ever be called once).

Comment: Thats, ill look into it :-)